# Deleting only one sign instead of all signs up to the last tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I delete blanks with the "Backspace" key on my keyboard Visual Studio Code always deletes all blanks up to the last tab. How can i get Visual Studio Code to only delete ONE blank when pressing the "Backspace" key, instead of deleting all blanks up to the last tab? 
To illustrate my question/problem, I made a short video which shows the behavior of Visual Studio code: https://youtu.be/zpaOXwfky84

I googled for such an option in VS Code, but didn't find anything. I can use the DEL key instead of the backspace to only delete one blank, but there must be an option to change this behavior, right?

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior for python in Visual Studio. Perhaps language specific? *(relevant question i.m.h.o.!)*. Perhaps there is a language specific behavior macro or ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a way you can change this behaviour just do the following to reach the settings.

> File > Preferences > Settings

Then search for *Use tab stops* and disable the checkbox.

And done I hope that's what you meant. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was EXACTLY what i wanted to have! 
Now i can use tab with the tab key (or shift+tab) and I can use normal backspace to delete only one blank :)